# Map one data model to another

Tags: java, mapping

The question is trivial, but I couldn't find an example.
I have to map one data model to another data model (common data model). How to do it without using any frameworks? These are very simple models, so frameworks are unnecessary.

```
public class A {
String name;
String lastName;
int age;
}
```

```
public class B {
String firstName;
String lastName;
}
```

Comment: I'd say manually, one field at a time. Or you could make a `Map` that maps one field of A to a field of `B` and use it to copy values from one class to the other. At which point you basically created a bug-ridden library and you were better off using [mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org) (which is a library, not a framework, btw) from the start...

Comment: just like `public static A mapToA() { b.name = a.firstName?; ... }` ?

Comment: Except for that `?` which I guess is a typo, yes, basically. But as I said, that's error-prone and is basically what mapstruct already does. Except it also generates null checks for intermediate operations in case you have other objects as instance members instead of strings or primitives.